# Background-attachment:fixed not working

Tags: android, cordova, background, attachment, fixed

I am using background-attachment:fixed for my phonegap application.
It work on browser but not work on my android phone.

Nobody knows where is the problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: most android versions don't support it

Comment: Now what is the solution?how can i solve it?

Comment: no solution, it not supported anymore, you'll have to find another way of doing the same effect or not use it at all

Comment: do you know another way to doing the same effect?Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no, I have never used background-attachment:fixed

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, I ended up using `background-attachment: local` and manually setting the `background-position` with `-left px`, `-top px`, then calculating the amount to scale width for `background-size` to match the parent's `background`

It looks great, but way too much computation and hacking for my taste

Comment: See -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010761/css-transparent-glass-modal-everything-else-darkened/40100652#40100652