# CSS -- transparent "glass" modal, everything else darkened

Tags: css, modal-dialog, background-image, background-attachment

> [**THE ANSWER: `background-attachment`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010761/css-trnsparent-glass-modal-everything-else-darkened/40100652#answer-40100652)

---

> ----- [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/hajices/edit?output) ----

---

The answer is to use `background-attachment`

[image: screenshot]

---

> **ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm working on a project where we want to display a modal that "sees through" to the backdrop, but everywhere outside of the modal panel is slightly masked.

I have successfully used `border: 10000px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)` with `border-radius: 10010px` but this is a hack, and I can't outline the modal with a `box-shadow`

Is there any standard way for doing this? Bonus points if you can think of a way to apply a transparency filter gradient to an image.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

> ---- [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/hajices/edit?output) ----

---

### The answer is to use `background-attachment`

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url(http://imgur.com/oVaQJ8F.png);
```

---

```
.modal-backdrop {
    background: url(myurl.png) center center / cover no-repeat fixed
}

.modal-panel {
    background: url(myurl.png) center center / cover no-repeat fixed
}
```

The best value would be `fixed` (not all devices support fixed) so that your backdrop and your modal can share the same viewport `X` and `Y` `(0, 0)` by default

You then scale with `background-size` percentages or `cover`

When using `background:` shorthand, make sure to use a `/` to separate `background-position` from `background-scale` amounts

---

I ran into a bug on an older device, so I used `local` then manually computed `leftX` and `topY` to line up backdrop and modal-panel `background-position` at `(0, 0)` on my viewport.

I then scaled both images with the same percentage, to cover the screen

I also used a gradient, credit -- [How to darken a background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26621579/1487102)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option you got here is to have a 3-rows where the middle one contains 3 columns and the top-bottom rows & left-right columns (of the middle row) have darkened background:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    tpl = '<div class="modal-reverse-container"><div class="r1"></div><div class="r2"><div class="c1"></div><div class="c2"></div><div class="c3"></div></div><div class="r3"></div></div>'
    $('body').append($(tpl));
    $('.modal-reverse-container').width($(document).width());
    $('.modal-reverse-container').height($(document).height());
    $('.modal-reverse-container r1, .modal-reverse-container r2').height($(document).height());
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.modal-reverse-container', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
.modal-reverse-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.modal-reverse-container .r1, .modal-reverse-container .r2, .modal-reverse-container .r3 {
  height: 33%;
}
.modal-reverse-container .r1, .modal-reverse-container .r3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.modal-reverse-container .r2 .c1, .modal-reverse-container .r2 .c2, .modal-reverse-container .r2 .c3 {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.modal-reverse-container .r2 .c3 {
  float: right;
}
.modal-reverse-container .r2 .c1, .modal-reverse-container .r2 .c3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/d950d9/fff" />
<div>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
<button>Set reverse-modal</button>
```

Comment: this is a good idea, but I don't think it would allow for `border-radius`!